# LARAVEL 8, PHP 8 SQLSTATE [42S22]: Столбец не найден: 1054 Неизвестный столбец '0' в 'списке полей'

Tags: php, mysql

Created a seed and a migration, the migration takes place, and when the launch, an error occurs:

```
SQLSTATE [42S22]: 
Column не найдено: 1054 Неизвестный столбца '0' в 'списке полей' 
(SQL: вставка в blog_categories( title, 0, parent_id) значения 
    (Без категории, Bez-kategorii, 0), 
    (Категория # 1 , kategoriya-1, 1), 
    (Категория # 2, категория-2, 1), 
    (Категория # 3, категория-3, 1), 
    (Категория # 4, категория-4, 1), 
    (Категория # 5, категория-5, 1) , 
    (Категория # 6, категория-6, 3), 
    (Категория # 7, категория-7, 3), 
    (Категория # 8, категория-8, 2), 
    (Категория # 9, категория-9, 2), 
    ( Категория №10, категория-10, 3)
)
```

Код миграции:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('blog_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigincrements('id');
            $table->biginteger('parent_id')->unsigned()->default(1);

            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('description')->nullable();

            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }
```

код сида:

```
 public function run()
    {
        $categories = [];

        $cName = 'Без категории';

        $categories [] = [
            'title'     => $cName,
            Str::of($cName)-> slug(),
            'parent_id' => 0,
        ];

        for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
            $cName = 'Категория #'.$i;
            $parentId = ($i > 4) ? rand(1, 4) : 1;
            $categories [] = [
                'title'     => $cName,
                Str::of($cName)-> slug(),
                'parent_id' => $parentId,
            ];
        }
        \DB::table('blog_categories')->insert($categories);
    }
```

Использую php 8.0, laravel 8.18

После мне подсказали и поправил предыдущий код на

```
"Slug"=> Str::of($cName)-> slug()
```

После очередного этот сид запустился, а другой выдал ошибку SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'at_published' in 'field list'
ошибка такая же, не могу понять в чем проблема? в документации не нашел ответа

```
 public function definition()
        {
            $title = $this->faker->sentence(rand(3, 8), true);
            $txt = $this->faker->realText(rand(1000, 4000));
            $isPublished = rand(1, 5) > 1;
    
            $createdAt = $this->faker->dateTimeBetween('-3 months', '-2 months');
    
            $data = [
                'category_id'   => rand(1, 10),
                'user_id'       => (rand(1, 5) == 5) ? 1 : 2,
                'title'         => $title,
                'slug'          => Str::slug($title),
                'excerpt'       => $this->faker->text(rand(40, 100)),
                'content_raw'   => $txt,
                'content_html'  => $txt,
                'is_published'  => $isPublished,
                'at_published'  => $isPublished ? $this->faker->dateTimeBetween('-2 months', '-1 days') : null,
                'created_at'    => $createdAt,
                'updated_at'    => $createdAt, 
            ];
    
            return $data;
            
        }
```

Comment: Перед Str::of($cName)-> slug() добавьте “slug” => так как иначе значение будет под ключом 0.

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov спасибо тебе добрейший человек) копался 2 дня, в документации так и не нашел такой синтаксис, но вот дилемма, у меня теперь фабрика ругается на такую же ошибку, посмотри пожалуйста, не могу найти в документации laravel правильный ответ

Comment: Ну а колонка `at_published` есть в таблице? Может она все-таки `published_at`?

Comment: @u_mulder капец я Алеша, спасибо)))))